# Logical problem of using fork() to handle multiple clients in socket in c

Tags: c, sockets, client, fork

I am currently using socket to write a server of a dice game to handle multiple clients, every time the server starts a new round of game (clients must be at least 3), there should be two random dice rolled to get two random `int` between 1-6, and the client side needs to guess the solution and send it to the server.

I am facing the logical problem that, I am using the `fork()` function to handle multiple clients, each round of the game must be a while loop, but at the same time, the loop keeps receiving connections, which means every time the `game_round()` function (roll two dices) runs, the program can still receive connections.

My question is, how can I modify my code to make the game start only if the clients is at least 3, and then do the next steps for each child process until there is only one client.

The game logic is:

1. Roll two dices to get a solution.
2. client1 sends the guess to server, 
        client2 sends the guess to server, clients3 sends .........
3. Server receive guesses and check, if client1 is wrong, lives-1,
        if correct, do nothing and send the lives information back to client.
4. Back to step 1 until there is only one client which is the winner.

Here is part of my server code:

```
    while(1){

           // Roll the dice
           game_round();

           socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client);
           client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client,                        &client_len);
           if(client_fd<0)
           {
                perror("connection error");
                exit(1);
           }

           printf("new client accepted.\n");

           if(childid=fork()==0)//child process
           {
                printf("child process: %d created.\n", getpid());
                printf("\n" );
                close(server_fd);// close listening

                // receive INIT and send information back
                init(client_fd, info);

                sleep(2);

                // send game begun message
                begun(client_fd);

                sleep(2);

                //send guess information
                guess(client_fd);

                sleep(2);

                //receive client's moves and process
                recv_proce_move(client_fd, move);

                check(info, round, move);

                sleep(2);

                // send lives back to clients, if lives is 0, close 
                   the child process
                // if the client's live is 0, close the connection
                send_lives(client_fd, move, info);
          }
          if(childid == 0){
               printf("game over");
               break;
          }
     }
```

Comment: where is the code that send answers? how do you connect to server?

Comment: I put the send function inside the new defined functions such as init(), guess(), just simply send some information back to the client

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your sockets into something like a select() function. A select function allows for you to block and wait for an event on multiple sockets and file descriptors at the same time.

Here is a good example:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html

Comment: Thanks first, do I still need use fork() function to do the send and check steps after using select() function? Because I realized that the select() uses a for loop to loop every client in that array, I am not pretty sure does the message or I could say information of each game round will arrive at each client at the same.